# How do I define an Icon in QT with a compile time predefined image?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, icons

I have a png file on disk at compile time. I'd like to have it included into the compiled executable.
How do I define such an icon in Qt?

Comment: Do you mean without loading the icon data from the resources?

Comment: I 'd like to include the resource into the executable, so that it's not loaded at runtime. Is that possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You basically need to use the Qt resource system.
Check out *Compiled-In Resources* [here](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/resources.html).

Lets say this this your resource file

```
<!DOCTYPE RCC><RCC version="1.0">
 <qresource>
     <file>images/copy.png</file>
     <file>images/cut.png</file>
     <file>images/paste.png</file>
 </qresource>
</RCC>
```

In your source you can now create QIcons by referencing images from the resource

```
QIcon(":/images/cut.png")
```

Don't forget to reference the resource file in your .pro

```
 RESOURCES = application.qrc
```

[This example](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/mainwindows-application.html) uses images in Resource file for the icons

Comment: perfect, and then - hoe do I define the Icon using that compiled-in resource?

Answer (score 7):

As an alternative to Qt's resource system, you can use (your favorite image conversion utility) to convert the .png file to .xpm format, and then add these lines to your .cpp file:

```
#include "my_converted_image.xpm"
[...]
QPixmap myPixmap((const char **) my_converted_image_xpm);
```

...where my_converted_image_xpm is the name of the character array declared near the top of the .xpm file.  This works because the .xpm image format is actually just C source code declaring a character array that is the bitmap, which QPixmap knows how to parse, e.g.:

```
/* XPM */
static const char * const my_converted_image_xpm[] = {
"16 16 65 1",
"       c None",
".      c #0F0F04",
[...]
"                "};
```

Answer (score 0):

If your using Qt-Creator, there's a resource editor available for you to use. Simply create a new resource file, add a prefix and add files. Qt-Creator will automatically add it into the project file. After that, select your image from your resource and your good to go